# Admob and ios6 problems

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ios6, admob, iad

I am updating my cocos2d app to ios6, but I have problems with advertising, I've decided not to stick more with iad landscape and ads. But admob not work for me, what I do is put an ad in AdMob landscape, and when I click on the ad and return to the app, the app is turned, but not the device, but the merits of the application, so you can not play, please help thanks

Comment: Can you show us some code showing how you're implementing your Admob ads and what you're setting the rootViewController to? Also, what version of AdMob and cocos2d are you using?